# assigning value in razor difficulty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having the following pice of code which is firing error

> Error 1   Invalid expression term '='

```
@{

  int Interest;

}

 <td>@if (@item.interest.HasValue)
    {

        @Interest= @item.interest.Value.ToString("F2");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When declaring a variable, this variable needs to be assigned:

```
@{
    string Interest = "";
}
```

and then:

```
@if (item.interest.HasValue)
{
    Interest = item.interest.Value.ToString("F2");
}
```

This being said doing something like this in a view is a very bad design. I mean things like declaring and assigning variables based on some condition is not a logic that should be placed in a view. The view is there to display data. This logic should go to your controller or view model.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your @if block you can address variables without the `@` sign.

```
@if (@item.interest.value) {
   @item= @item.interest.Value
}
```

Is interpreted as:

```
@if (@item.interest.value) {
     Write(item=);
     Write(@item.interest.Value);
}
```

As you can see `Write(item=)` is not valid C# code.

You should use:

```
 @if (item.interest.value) {
     item = item.interest....
 }
```

The reason your `if (@item....)` statement compiles, with the `@` sign. Is because you can prefix an identifier with the @ to use reserved words as identifier names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{

string Interest;
}

 <td>@if (@item.interest.HasValue)
    {

        Interest= @item.interest.Value.ToString("F2");
    }
```

By the way you are trying to assign a string (the result of ToString()) to an integer. This will not work.